# Pl/SQL Procedure CURSOR For Loop

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, toad

I am new to PL/SQL and experimenting with CURSOR.  I desire to verify an insertion procedure so I wrote another procedure to do so.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE verify_insert

IS

   CURSOR map_cur IS

      SELECT Page_ID_NBR, Page_Type, Page_Dcpn FROM SSC_Page_Map;

      map_rec map_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

   OPEN map_cur;

   FOR map_rec in map_cur

   LOOP

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: ' || map_cur.Page_ID_NBR || ' ' || 'Type' ||  map_cur.Page_Type || ' ' || 'Description' || map_cur.Page_Dcpn);   

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE map_cur;

END;

SHOW ERRORS PROCEDURE verify_insert;
```

I am getting the following message

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
19/44   PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'MAP_CUR' reference is out of scope
19/5    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
(47: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

I also see

```
Errors for PROCEDURE VERIFY_INSERT

LINE/COL ERROR                                                            
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
19/44    PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'MAP_CUR' reference is out of sco


19/5     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

As I wrote, I am new and trying to cobble together knowledge of PL/SQL from `Oracle PL/SQL Programming (Feuerstein)` and the net.  Coming together but not as fast as I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loop is fetching a row from the cursor into the record type.  Inside the loop, you'd want to read the data from the record type.  In your `dbms_output.put_line` call, you'd want to reference the record not the cursor.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: ' || map_rec.Page_ID_NBR || 
              ' ' || 'Type' || map_rec.Page_Type || 
              ' ' || 'Description' || map_rec.Page_Dcpn);
```

Comment: Thank you. What I get for just copying bad examples off the net.  Can you please point me to a great site where I can quickly increase my knowledge and avoid the hunt and peck approach that has its' pitfalls?  Thank you.